# Group List with attribute and add another Attribute

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

I have a List of objects. I to assign a color to every object with a similar attibute ie.ParentId.I have done something like so:-

```
Map<String, String> idToColorMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
            int colorIndex = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < myParentList.size(); i++)
            {
                if (myParentList.size() > 1 && !idToColorMap.containsKey(myParentList.get(i).getParentId())) {
                    Parent currentParent = myParentList.get(i);
                    currentParent.setColor(colorPallete[colorIndex]);
                    idToColorMap.put(currentParent.getParentId(), colorPallete[colorIndex]);

                    for (int j = i + 1; j < myFinalParentList.size(); j++) {
                        if (myParentList.get(j).getParentId().equals(currentParent.getParentId())) {
                            myParentList.get(j).setColor(colorPallete[colorIndex]);
                        }
                    }

                    if (++colorIndex == colorPallete.length) {
                        colorIndex = 0;
                    }
                } else {
                    myParentList.get(0).setColor(colorPallete[0]);
                    idToColorMap.put(myParentList.get(0).getParentId(), colorPallete[0]);
                }
            }
```

But with this only the first item in the list with the ParentId is assigned the color and not all the items with the same ParentId

Comment: I don't understand why do you do another `for` in your test. Are your myParentList and myFinalParentList different?

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes from your tests.

```
// OK for parent[0] but not all other
if (myParentList.size() > 1 && !idToColorMap.containsKey(myParentList.get(i).getParentId())) { 
    ...
} 
// Will only set you first parent not all others
else {
    myParentList.get(0).setColor(colorPallete[0]);
    idToColorMap.put(myParentList.get(0).getParentId(), colorPallete[0]);
}
```

With your test you can only enter the `if` if you have not encounter this parentId. But if you have already encountered one then you go to `else` where you only change parent[0].

You should separate your test.

EDIT :

Here is something that should work (didn't test, maybe some minor correction has to be done). Plus: I didn't understand what is your myFinalParentList so I didn't put it in here. Just add your foreach after my code. if necessary

```
Map<String, String> idToColorMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
int colorIndex = 0;
String colorPallete = ...;
for (Parent parent : myParentList) {
    // if is not in idIdColorMap then I add it
    if (!idToColorMap.containsKey(parent.getParentId()) {
        idToColorMap.put(parent.getParentId(), colorPallete[colorIndex]);
        // increment colorIndex
        if (colorIndex + 1 == colorPallete.length) {
            colorIndex = 0;
        } else {
            colorIndex++;
        }
    }
    // Set Parent's Color
    parent.setColor(idToColorMap.get(parent.getId());
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. Can you please elaborate? I just want to associate a color for similar Id's. Is there a better way to do it?